# No notification sound, even though enabled

Tags: sms, notifications, nexus-4

My phone doesn't play the notification sound (only vibration) for any app. This is particularly annoying when I get an SMS as I never notice when I get a message.

It appears that *all* notification sounds are affected, because the StackExchange app **notification triggers a vibrate but no sound** either. It has been working until a few days ago, and I don't know what I've changed lately.

In my `Settings > Sound`, I can "preview" the `Settings > Sound > phone ringtone` by simply choosing any of the ones listed. So far so good.
When I do the same with `Settings > Sound > default notification sound`, the phone stays silent. It does not matter whether I touch one of the stock sounds or one that I provided myself (which used to work!).

**How can I make the notification sounds play again?**

- Device: Nexus 4
- OS: stock Android 4.4.4, rooted.
- This problem exists since a few days.
- I have tried rebooting the phone, but it didn't help.
- The volumes are turned up. In `Settings > Sound > Volumes`, all three sliders are somewhere in the middle.
- The stock `Messaging` app is the default app for text messages. I have Hangouts installed but it's not in use. I also had a few others installed because I wanted to test them, but I have now uninstalled them.

Comment: Is this only on preview or does it not play at all?

Comment: No sound when I get SMS. The above was my investigation. I'll edit my post.